# 'Validation' does not exist in the namespace 'System.Data.Entity' when building on Team City

Tags: c#, entity-framework, continuous-integration, teamcity, assembly-references

I have a project that is working perfectly on my computer, but when trying to build it on Team City i get the following build error for source files where i have

```
using System.Data.Entity;    
using System.Data.Entity.Validation;


CS0234: The type or namespace name 'Validation' does not exist in the namespace 'System.Data.Entity' (are you missing an assembly reference?)
```

Do I need to install Entity Framework manually on the server running Team City for this to work?

**Update after activating Nuget Restore:**

This must be some kind of configuration issue.

I can see in the build log that the build process is copying the .dll:

```
[Copy] Copying file from "D:\TeamCity\agent1\work\541c9f462afc285d\packages\EntityFramework.5.0.0\lib\net45\EntityFr    amework.dll" to "bin\Release\EntityFramework.dll".
[16:51:55][Copy] Copying file from "D:\TeamCity\agent1\work\541c9f462afc285d\packages\EntityFramework.5.0.0\lib\net45\EntityFramework.xml" to "bin\Release\EntityFramework.xml".
```

But shortly after, it is considering a bunch of different locations, but not including the bin\Release\EntityFramework.dll" folder.

**Update 2:**

Manually copying the .dll to the bin/release folder of my class library helped the build to pass, but obviously this is no viable solution, so will need to keep on finding out how to configure this correctly.

**Update 3:**

Never did find a satisfying solution for this I am sad to say, so any genius that can  solve this are very welcome. :)

Comment: Have you tried using a pre-build task that would fetch the EF via NuGet? This way you don't have have to install EF on your build server. TeamCity gets it when it tries to build it.

Comment: I second what @Shriroop wrote. Guess TeamCity is attempting to load the old Entity Framework thats included with the .NET framework (which does not have `System.Data.Entity.Validation`).

Comment: Let us all know if it works or not.

Comment: Did this work for you in the end?

Comment: Sadly no, i was able to do a temporary fix by manually copying the entity framework dll files to the correct folder on the build server, but that is not really a solution. So still a bit frustrated. The correct .dll is downloaded by nuget, but will not be placed in correct folder for the build to work.

Answer (score 1):

As an error suggested you are missing assembly. And as @Shriroop suggested this is in EF packge.

Before your compile step, add Nuget Installer step. There are few options you should set, Path to solution name and I suggest you use nuget 2.7+ and Restore mode: Restore.

To install latest nuget version in teamcity go to Administration > Nuget Settings > NuGet.exe and fetch latest version.

Here is a sample of NuGet Installer step: http://img.hihi.si/Upload/5PUm.png

Comment: Hmm, I find in the build log that the EF package is downloaded, but it seems that the build process does not look in the correct location afterwards.

Comment: Can you provide full log and describe all build steps